# How to understand which ANN model is being used?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I'm working on a simple project that involves a bit of Artificial Intelligence in the sense that it is being trained with a certain set of values, and then it uses those values to match patterns and return whatever is desired to the user. While pondering upon it and reading a bit on Artificial Intelligence, I stumbled upon the question that which [ANN model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) is being used in my project? A read from various pages on the Internet and specially the one that I linked, say these specific lines on many occasions : *"models are also intimately associated with a particular learning algorithm or learning rule "* . 
The simple outline of my project is that it gets trained using a set of values(hence, the learning is supervised) , and it matches patterns and sends in responses based on them. So how to make out which ANN model am I using?

I feel that this question most probably will get down voted or closed, but it's always better to ask than not ask. :-)

***Edit :***

My project is a simpler version of [this](http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/42/page1.html) . It says it uses a Kohonen Neural Network, which I guess is not a general model and something developed by the Heaton Research Team. Anyways, this was just to give a hint as to what my project actually does. I do not know how he trains his system, but I train my system on the basis of Strokes(their length,number of strokes,etc.).

**EDIT 2 : (a note for the down-voter)**
I'm not an AI specialist or something , I'm just a developer who's asked for a guidance into a new domain for myself. You could have tried like alfa and Franck did. Thanks for atleast looking into the question!

Comment: I think the only person who can say what you implemented is you, since you did not provide any source code. And if you don't know what kind of ANN you implemented you most likely did not implement an ANN. :) Of course, ANN is a very general learning structure. But not every supervised learning method is a neural network. How do you train? How do you adjust your parameters? What kind of model (mathematical formula) do you have?

Comment: I don't have much idea about these terms, as I thought more in the terms of a developer and not in these terms. It works simply - I store patterns for it,manually,one at a time. Save it into a database. Then when the user inputs any pattern, the program refers to the database to find which is the most appropriate pattern, and returns a result for it.

Comment: How are you training the thing if you don't know what neuron model you're using?

Comment: @Novak It's a very basic and simple handwriting recognition application. I don't know what neuron model to use because as a developer I know how to train the system - based on writing strokes. Every alphabet has a particular style of writing and that's how different strokes work for different alphabets. And that's how the system recognizes the alphabets too.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what you're asking.  Are you asking what neuron model you *should use* for a handwriting application?  Or are you saying you've built a handwriting recognition application and could we please tell you what neuron model you *have used*?

Comment: @Novak the second one. I've built a handwriting recognition application and I'm unable to understand what neuron model have I used. I know without having a proper idea about my application it'll be tough to estimate what model have I used, but I guess alfa has provided a good enough link to study about the model that I have mentioned in my edit to the question. But you are more than welcome to provide any other proper sources too. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you calculate the **distance** to your patterns then you actually implemented [k-nearest-neighbours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) (1-nearest-neighbours). That has nothing to do with a neural network. You have no training phase here. The neural networks that are most similar to your classifier are radial basis functions or support vector machines. But you have to train these classifiers and you have weights that will be adjusted during this training phase. The goal of a training phase is to find a simpler representation of the concept you want to represent. The advantage is: your classification will be faster in the future. You don't have to look at all your training data again.

**edit:** OK, you can read about Kohonen networks here: [Neural Network FAQ: How many kinds of Kohonen networks exist? (And what is k-means?)](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ.html#A_Kohonen).

Comment: Please read this page: ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ.html#A_Kohonen

Comment: Thank you! Seems exactly the kind of thing I wanted! Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To build an ANN, you need to choose a [neuron model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_neuron_model) as well as a [network structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_artificial_neural_networks).